# CSS Problem with my topNav in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

CSS Problem with my topNav in IE6

HTML Page:
http://www.faressoft.net

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have block elements within inline elements, ie you have divs in you `ul` tag, before your `li`, This is not allowed, and may be causing the issues your seeing in IE

You also use quite a few divs within your `table` tag between your `tr` and `td` tags. This is also not allowed.